# Two page continuous view in Lion Preview?

Tags: macos, preview

Is there some way to get back the side-by-side page view from Snow Leopard with the continuous scrolling? From the View menu in Lion Preview, it appears they're mutually exclusive now. I can't help shake the idea that Lion was designed by someone without a desktop Mac.

Comment: Unless there is some elaborate hack I'd say it impossible because as you said its mutually exclusive in the interface. Maybe filing a bug with Apple would help. In the mean time Skim still offers this option.

Comment: > *I can't help shake the idea that Lion was designed by someone without a desktop Mac.* LOL

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is one of those things that really makes me wonder "If it's not broken why fix it?".

Other than switching to another application that might give you back the lost functionality, I only have one suggestion at the moment. This is how I've been able to use Preview (5.5) and *still* get two page (side by side) continuous scrolling:

> 1. Open up your pdf, document, etc. in Preview.app
> 2. File > Print or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>
> 3. In the Print Dialog Box click  Preview > Change to Layout [ 2 pages ]
> 4. Lastly, click PDF > Open PDF in Preview.

You should now see your document layout as two pages and you can scroll continuously. I realize it's far from ideal, although it is a way to still use Preview exclusively, yet still have similar functionality as before. I hope they will fix it; I shouldn't have to be thinking of ways like this to use it like it could have been. ;-)

[image: Two page continuous / workaround]

Comment: Hope this gets fixed soon in a lion update, but in the meantime, I love it!

Comment: Awesome idea! I was so frustrated with the default view of Preview and your fix is just brilliant.

Comment: This workaround is really fantastic! Apple has not yet fixed it, even in Mavericks.

Answer (score 8):

The free app [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net) supports continuous-scroll side-by-side pages. To use that view, select the menu item *PDF* → *PDF Display* → *Two Pages Continuous*.

[image: Skim displaying a PDF in Two Pages Continuous view]

Also, if the left-hand page is wrongly displayed on the right side and vice versa, you can fix that by toggling *Book Mode* in the same menu.

Comment: Skim is absolutely fantastic. Much better than preview

Answer (score 1):

Right click PDF document. Select "Open With". Select "Safari.app". Right click on a page of the document within Safari. Select "Two Pages Continuous".

Very stupid for Apple to remove this feature from Preview in the latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can get that view with [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince), which is installable via `brew install evince`.

[image]